# How to select correct contour the group of six digits

Tags: python, opencv, ocr

I have a batch of screenshots like here:

[image: Test screenshot]

and I try to detect the region with six digits and recognize them. The second part works like a charm. I have a problem detecting the correct region because it can be placed with a shift depending on screen dimensions. For example, crop image looks like this:

[image: Cropped image]

Seems it looks ok, but I have to add some workaround in code to select the right place.

My code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 6))
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (8, 8))

# Load and resize image to standard size
img0 = Image.open('./data/test.png')
img0.thumbnail((720, 1423))
img = np.array(img0)

# The magic from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, rectKernel)

gradX = cv2.Sobel(tophat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
gradX = np.absolute(gradX)
(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))
gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)))
gradX = gradX.astype("uint8")

gradX = cv2.morphologyEx(gradX, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rectKernel)
thresh = cv2.threshold(gradX, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)

cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
locs = []

for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ar = w / h
    if x > 140 and x < 220 and w > 100 and h > 12 and h < 20 and ar >= 4 and ar <= 6:
        locs.append((x, y, w, h))

# Calculate the crop rectangle 
LEFT_TOP = (181, 316)
RIGHT_BOTTOM = (299, 346)
if len(locs) > 0:
    (x, y, w, h) = locs[0]
    LEFT_TOP = (x - 5, y - 5) # workaround place
    RIGHT_BOTTOM = (x + w + 5, y + h) # workaround place
print(LEFT_TOP, RIGHT_BOTTOM)
img1 = img0.crop(LEFT_TOP + RIGHT_BOTTOM)
```

Selected contour looks like:

[image: Screenshot with contour]

It selects a contour smaller than the actual region. Why? How to fix it?

Thank you!

Test file:
[image: Test png for testing]

Comment: When executing your code, I am getting `locs = []`. It is most likely that you didn't post `'./data/test.png'`, but posted some other image instead. Please add the `import` statements to your posted code.

Comment: Added import lines and test image.

Comment: Now I am getting nice digits after adding `img1.save('./data/digits.png')`. Here is the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ElSqo.png). OK I saw the "workaround place"

Comment: Yes, if you remove workaround '+5', the result crop file will cut off part of digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no magics in software...

Inappropriate filters "eats" part of your digits.

- Remove the tophat filter.
- Remove the Sobel filter.
- Replace `cv2.THRESH_BINARY` with `cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV`.
- Increase the size of `sqKernel`.

I recommend you to draw the contours, and show (or save) intermediate results for testing.

---

Here is the modified code:

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
#from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from PIL import Image

#rectKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 6))
#sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (8, 8))
sqKernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_RECT, (15, 11))

# Load and resize image to standard size
img0 = Image.open('./data/test.png')
img0.thumbnail((720, 1423))
img = np.array(img0)

# The magic from https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/07/17/credit-card-ocr-with-opencv-and-python/
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGB2GRAY)
#tophat = cv2.morphologyEx(gray, cv2.MORPH_TOPHAT, rectKernel)

#gradX = cv2.Sobel(tophat, ddepth=cv2.CV_32F, dx=1, dy=0, ksize=-1)
#gradX = np.absolute(gradX)
#(minVal, maxVal) = (np.min(gradX), np.max(gradX))
#gradX = (255 * ((gradX - minVal) / (maxVal - minVal)))
#gradX = gradX.astype("uint8")

#gradX = cv2.morphologyEx(gradX, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, rectKernel)
#thresh = cv2.threshold(gradX, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV | cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
thresh = cv2.morphologyEx(thresh, cv2.MORPH_CLOSE, sqKernel)

cnts, _ = cv2.findContours(thresh.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
locs = []


# Draw contours for testing
tmp_im = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_RGBA2BGR)
cv2.drawContours(tmp_im, cnts, -1, (0, 255, 0), 1)  # Draw green line around the contour
cv2.imshow('tmp_im', tmp_im)
cv2.waitKey()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite('./data/tmp_im.png', tmp_im)


for (i, c) in enumerate(cnts):
    (x, y, w, h) = cv2.boundingRect(c)
    ar = w / h
    if x > 140 and x < 220 and w > 100 and h > 12 and h < 20 and ar >= 4 and ar <= 6:
        locs.append((x, y, w, h))

# Calculate the crop rectangle 
LEFT_TOP = (181, 316)
RIGHT_BOTTOM = (299, 346)
if len(locs) > 0:
    (x, y, w, h) = locs[0]
    #LEFT_TOP = (x - 5, y - 5) # workaround place
    #RIGHT_BOTTOM = (x + w + 5, y + h) # workaround place
    LEFT_TOP = (x, y) # workaround place
    RIGHT_BOTTOM = (x + w, y + h) # workaround place

print(LEFT_TOP, RIGHT_BOTTOM)
img1 = img0.crop(LEFT_TOP + RIGHT_BOTTOM)

img1.show()
img1.save('./data/digits.png')
```

---

Result:
[image]

`tmp_img` (for testing):
[image]